# Can we set permission for Custom Setting object for Different Profile

Tags: profile, customsetting

Actually we don't want to show some details to other profile user.
I have researched solution for this problem but didn't find a answers for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Under Setup > Manager Users > Profiles then look for Customize Application under Administrative Permissions. This applies to all users that share this profile.

You will have to change this for all profiles that you don't want to be able to change custom settings. (This will also remove the ability to do most configuration changes from these users - that's what "Customize Application" means.)

[Referenced Link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_manage_data.htm&language=en)

Answer (score 1):

How we solved this was we added another field Profiles Permitted on the custom setting. In it we enter a comma-delimitted list of profiles that this setting applies to. If blank, then it means all profiles. Then in the code that refers to this setting we query for the setting where the current user profile is in Profiles Permitted or Profiles Permitted = null.